Sum of terms in a recurrence relation
Problem: Fix a $T \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the recurrence $a_{r + 1} = a_{r} + a_{r} ^ {2}$, where $r \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$ and $a_{0} = \frac{1}{T}$. Prove that $\sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} a_{r} = \Omega(\log T)$.
Fact: When $a_{0} = 1$, the recurrence is well known (https://oeis.org/A007018).
Attempts: I checked through a quick numerical simulation that the desired quantity is indeed $\Omega(\log T)$, however, have not been able to formally prove it. My attempts at studying the recurrence are the following:

It is easy to show via induction that $a_{r} \le \frac{1}{T - r}$ for all $r = 0, 1, \dots, T - 1$ which then yields $\sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} a_{r} = \mathcal{O}(\log T)$. However, such a statement does not hold with the inequality reversed, i.e. it is not the case that $a_{r} = \Omega(\frac{1}{T - r})$. If it were the case, then $a_{T - 1} = \Omega(1)$ for any $T \in \mathbb{N}$. However, on plotting the variation of $a_{T - 1}$ versus $T$, I found that the curve is monotonically decreasing and seems to converge to $0$ (the decrease is quite slow however, similar to the slow increment of the Harmonic Series).

To prove that $\sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} a_{r} = \Omega(\log T)$, it is sufficient to prove that $a_{T} \le \frac{1}{T} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{\log T})$. This is because, rewriting the recurrence in a slightly different form $\frac{1}{a_{r}} - \frac{1}{a_{r + 1}} = \frac{1}{a_{r} + 1}$ and summing over $r = 0, \dots, T - 1$, we obtain $\frac{1}{a_{0}} - \frac{1}{a_{T}} = \sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} \frac{1}{a_{r} + 1}$. Next, applying the AM-HM inequality $$\sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} (a_{r} + 1) \ge \frac{T ^ {2}}{\sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} \frac{1}{a_r + 1}} =  \frac{T ^ {2}}{T - \frac{1}{a_{T}}} \implies \sum_{r = 0} ^ {T - 1} a_{r} \ge \frac{1}{a_{T} - \frac{1}{T}}.$$
However, I have not been able to prove the desired upper bound on $a_T$.


Any help in proving the desired claim is highly appreciated.

(Communicated to me by Fedja). Write $a_r = \frac{1}{T-r+\lambda_r}$. Then $$\lambda_{r+1} = \lambda_r+\frac{1-\lambda_{r+1}+\lambda_r}{T-r+\lambda_r}.$$ This implies, by induction, that $\lambda_r \le \frac{1}{T}+\frac{1}{T-1}+\dots+\frac{1}{T-(r-1)}$; this will suffice, since it implies $\lambda_r \le \log T$ for each $r$. Indeed, the base case $r=0$ is true since $\lambda_0 = 0$, and, for the induction step, there is nothing to prove if $\lambda_{r+1} \le \lambda_r$, whilst if $\lambda_{r+1} > \lambda_r$, the display implies $\lambda_{r+1} \le \lambda_r+\frac{1}{T-r}$, as desired.

Thank you @mathworker21 for posting a beautiful solution and Fedja for communicating the problem. The solution is quite clever and I highly appreciate your help :)
